# How can I replace the downlight in my ceiling with the new one I bought?

Tags: lighting

After 5 years in our house, the living room ceiling downlight went out.  I removed it and bought a new one.  Plugging it in the circuit is no problem, but I can't figure out how to connect the fixture to the ceiling so that it will stay in place.

The old downlight hooked up to two torsion spring brackets.  There is a cannister that connects to the hole in the ceiling; the torsion spring brackets must have somehow connected to or pressed against the cannister, holding the fixture in place.  The new downlight instructions say that the torsion spring brackets should sit inside some things sticking out of the cannister, but the cannister has no such things sticking out.  I've tried to tape the torsion spring brackets onto the cannister, but that doesn't work.  The light kind of hangs a bit below the ceiling if I do that.

I'd be happy to just buy a whole new cannister and light, but I don't know if that requires rewiring something.

Pictures:

> [image: Blockquote]

[image: The new downlight]

[image: The hole where the cannister can be placed into the ceiling]

[image: The cannister. I attached torsion spring brackets to it in an ad hoc way.]

[image: Underside of the downlight]

[image: The cannister with the torsion spring brackets that I taped on]

[image: The ceiling.]

Comment: I don't see any torsion springs in your pictures. The things torsion springs fit into is is in your 6th or next to last picture. The two hooks at the end of the silver bracket. There might or might not also be a set die-cut into the sides of your can, not folded out, but not visible in the pictures. If so, they could be folded out. But you'd need torsion springs you don't show either way.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to take a picture of the torsion springs.   I can hook them in.  The problem is that there is nothing keeping the fixture flush wish the ceiling, so it just hangs out a centimeter or so below the ceiling...

Answer (score 0):

Does your canister (in the ceiling) have some vertical cut out slots along the sides? (I couldn't quite tell from the photos). If so, then you can squeeze the torsion springs into the slots. Sometimes you have to try different combinations of the slots, because they might not line up directly with the springs. Usually you can work it so that the light sits flush. If not, you can buy gaskets that help close the gap (and also help with reducing heat loss).

My canisters didn't have the extruding ears, and that's the process I used. On some canisters that didn't have the slots, I drilled a few holes into the canister for the springs. You can actually do this without removing the cans if you have a 90 degree drill, otherwise the bit tends to slide along the metal.

Comment: No, the cannister (which is not in the ceiling at the moment, but which can be loaded into the recess) doesn't really have slots.  Well, the inside is composed of many small grooves, but there wasn't really enough purchase there to be helpful.  But I taped the torsion spring brackets onto the top of the cannister.

Comment: There is just nothing holding the light flush with the ceiling.